# Install4j: Turning off "Suggest application directory"

Tags: install4j

In our "Installation Location" screen we have switched off "Suggest application directory" because it was appending a suffix to the directory users chose (not sure where the suffix came from as different people where seeing different things with the same build).

I wanted to know what kind of impact this change could have as the screen help says: "[...] only switch this off if you substitute a different installation directory in the screen validation".

We don't actually substitute the directory in the screen validation, however before showing the Welcome screen we do run an action to set an initial installation directory our users can override.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the "Installation location" screen appends the installation directory name that you have configured in the media wizard.

If you turn off “Suggest application directory”, and a user selects "C:\Program Files" as the installation directory, the application will be directly installed into that directory, which is not desirable.